# Bar chart chartjs border control

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, border

First ticket for me.

I am kind of stuck with a simple requirement.

I would like to put a black border on this bar chart.

```html
CFFCHART(
        'my-chart',
        {
            type:'bar',
            data:{
                labels:['YOUR OVERALL SCENARIO', 'MARKET IMPLIED SCENARIO', 'WORST CASE SCENARIO', 'BASE CASE SCENARIO', 'BEST CASE SCENARIO'],
                    datasets:[
                        {
label:'UPSIDE/DOWNSIDE SCENARII ANALYSIS',
data:[fieldname363, fieldname331, fieldname153, fieldname61, fieldname165],
backgroundColor:['rgba(255,255,255, 0.4)', 'grey', 'rgba(255,0,0, 0.4)', 'rgba(60,179,113, 0.4)', 'rgba(0,0,255, 0.4']
                        }
                    ]
            }
        }
    )
```

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Manage to find the solution, with :

Answer (score 1):

```
CFFCHART(
        'my-chart',
        {
            type:'bar',
            data:{
                labels:['YOUR OVERALL SCENARIO', 'MARKET IMPLIED SCENARIO', 'WORST CASE SCENARIO', 'BASE CASE SCENARIO', 'BEST CASE SCENARIO'],
                    datasets:[
                        {
label:'UPSIDE/DOWNSIDE SCENARII ANALYSIS',
data:[fieldname363, fieldname331, fieldname153, fieldname61, fieldname165],
backgroundColor:['rgba(255,255,255, 0.4)', 'grey', 'rgba(255,0,0, 0.4)', 'rgba(60,179,113, 0.4)', 'rgba(0,0,255, 0.4'],
borderWidth: 2,
borderColor:['rgba(0,0,0)','rgba(0,0,0)','rgba(0,0,0)','rgba(0,0,0)','rgba(0,0,0)']
                        }
                    ]
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear if you want a border around your entire chart or around the bars.

If you want border around the bars:

You can simply insert a borderColor array into your dataset. Check my example:

```js
    var ctx = document.getElementById("my-chart").getContext("2d");
    console.log('hi', ctx)
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',/*from   w  ww.j  a  va2  s . c  o m*/
    data: {
        labels:['YOUR OVERALL SCENARIO', 'MARKET IMPLIED SCENARIO', 'WORST CASE SCENARIO', 'BASE CASE SCENARIO', 'BEST CASE SCENARIO'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'UPSIDE/DOWNSIDE SCENARII ANALYSIS',
            data: ['34', '55', '77', '96', '344'],
            backgroundColor:['rgba(255,255,255, 0.4)', 'grey', 'rgba(255,0,0, 0.4)', 'rgba(60,179,113, 0.4)', 'rgba(0,0,255, 0.4'],
            borderColor: [
                'black',
                'black',
                'black',
                'black',
                'black',
                'black'
            ],
            borderWidth: 4
        }]
    }, 
});
```

```html
<html>
   <head> 
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
   </head> 
   <body>  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>   
      <div> 
         <canvas id="my-chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas> 
      </div>   
   </body>
</html>
```

Now if you want a border all around your chart, you can just wrap the canvas inside a div and add a border to it.

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;"> 
<canvas id="my-chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas> 
</div>
```

I hope it can help you.